# How to check the status of the field in the table for all parents in the tree

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Source table - category tree

```
id, parent_id, state, name
```

We have

```
id = 4, parent_id = 0, state = 1, name = SubCategory 0 (root)
id = 8, parent_id = 4, state = 0, name = SubCategory 1
id = 15, parent_id = 8, state = 1, name = SubCategory 2
id = 36, parent_id = 15, state = 1, name = SubCategory 3
```

As a single request to check the state of all parents, and if at least one state = 0, then the result of the sample should be 0 lines

Tried WITH RECURSIVE

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, state, parent_id, name) AS (
      SELECT     id,
                 state,
                 parent_id,
                 name
      FROM       t_pages
      WHERE      id = 36
      UNION ALL
      SELECT     p.id,
                 p.state,
                 p.parent_id,
                 p.name
      FROM       t_pages p
      INNER JOIN cte
                 ON p.id = cte.parent_id
                 AND p.state = 1
    )
    SELECT * FROM cte;
```

But I don’t think how to set the condition correctly. In the above version, always 1 option gives (which is logical)
Well, this is too slow - 0.5 seconds per table with 200 entries

There are other options?

**UPD: fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ecdbd0252a87aed8d3c6f5b3a31e0297**

Comment: Hmmm... Adding `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';` before and after the query -- this shows that only a few rows are touched.

Comment: Hmmm... Adding `SELECT NOW(3);` to your fiddle shows only 11 _milliseconds_ total time for the query.